# Application_Error fired on different thread

Tags: asp.net, exception, iis, httpapplication

Recently we started seeing a problem where the Application_Error event handler (for [HttpApplication.Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.error.aspx)) is being invoked on a different thread from where the request was handled.

Things we have changed recently:

- 32 bit to 64 bit
- Classic to Integrated Pipeline mode

For what its worth, here's some code that might help explain this:
In one representative test, the thread shown on the page is 7, where the one in the email is 10.

```
//The application
public class MyApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected virtual void Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    {
        var threadId = System.Threading.Thread.Current.ManagedThreadId;
        SendEmail("There was an error on threadId " + threadId.ToString());
    }

    private void SendEmail(string message)  
    { 
        //snip 
    }
}

//Some aspx page
<%
var threadId = System.Threading.Thread.Current.ManagedThreadId;
throw new Exception("This is a test.  ThreadId = " + threadID.ToString());
%>
```

This causes issues for us as we are storing authentication information in [Thread.CurrentPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx), and we need to log that information with the exception.

How can I either keep it on the same thread, or make IIS give me the CurrentPrincipal from the original thread?

Comment: This is because thats the thread that the error is being thrown on.  What is the exception that is being thrown?

Comment: @Justin I think you misunderstand.  This can be any exception, and the thread that the exception is thrown on is different from the thread that Application_Error is being fired on.  This is used for logging any unhandled exception in the application.

Comment: Hmm... why exactly do you need the threadID to be the same? I recommend also clarifying your question by asking an actual question. So far all you do is say "I see this behavior" and don't tell us why this matters or what your actual problem is

Comment: in my question: "we are storing authentication information in Thread.CurrentPrincipal"  we need the CurrentPrincipal for logging purposes.  It was there before but I have moved it to the bottom to bring attention to it.

Comment: Yea, I misread that and skimmed over that portion wehn I first commented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're seeing this behavior because ASP.Net uses different threads for executing an ASP.Net page and handling an error.

You should be able to solve your problem by using `HttpContext.Current.User` instead. However, there can be subtle differences between these. You can check [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx) article that explains that they can point to different objects (but basically only do if you make it that way)

Comment: Interesting.  I will give that a try!

Comment: Unfortunately the Request.Context.Current.User is just a GenericPrincipal.  Note that the Principal we are looking for is one that we are pushing into Thread.CurrentPrincipal via our own authentication mechanisms, rather than an IIS authenticated user.

Comment: Well then the big question is why you push to Thread instead of Request.. the blog post I mention basically says having these out of sync is a bad practice